# Unparseable Date Or Wrong date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Hi I know there are many post on this but I can't figure out what's happening. I'm getting a date as a String from db and trying to convert it to another form.

Didn't understand that had to FIRST parse the string and then use another SimpleDateFormat to Format that date. I know get what I expected when printed.

Date one: Mon Jun 16 04:00:00 EDT 2014

06-16-2014

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;


    public class DateCheck {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                String str = "2014-06-16 04:00:00.0";
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
                Date date1 =  df.parse(str);
                System.out.println(" Date one: " + date1);
                 SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");       

                System.out.println(df2.format(date1));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }

2 things to note, if i uncomment out the setLenient method i get unparseable date exception.
If commented out i get:Mon Oct 06 00:00:00 EDT 2183
Any help?

EDIT: Sorry that was just stupid.  I know get Thu Jan 16 00:06:00 EST 2014
 which is correct but i wanted it like 01-16-14
```

Comment: You've told it to expect `MM-dd-yy`. You've passed it `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM.m`. You're surprised it's confused...

Comment: So, with the date format you've specified, this would be the 6th day of the 2014th month of the year 09.  Why are you expecting this to work?

Comment: Note, you should probably use yyyy-MM-dd to indicate months isntead of minutes..

Answer (score 0):

Your format doesn't match your input `String`.

The input `String` is in the format of "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm.s" (there is an assumption on the format as we don't have enough information to make an accurate prediction)

```
String str = "2014-06-09 00:00.0";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy");
df.setLenient(true);
Date result = df.parse(str);
```

Which outputs

```
Mon Jun 09 00:00:00 EST 2014
```

So either your format is wrong or the value in the database is wrong.  This will depended on your requirements